Why does file explorer use close to 100% cpu with no tabs open?
One of our employees have an issue on their laptop where the laptop would suddenly run “hot” due to file explorer utilizing most of the cpu.
Details are as follows:
OS: Windows 10
Issue: Near 100% utilization of the cpu by File explorer, even with no tabs open. The fan speeds up and the cpu thermal throttles in the end.
Temporary resolution: Restarting file explorer via Task Manager.
After restarting the background file explorer process the cpu utilization returns to normal, until it acts up again at seemingly random intervals. Usually a few hours later.
What I can’t explain is why this happens even when there are no file explorer tabs open.
My question is basically what is the cause and how can I permanently fix it.

Is the computer fully updated? What version/build of Windows 10 is being run? What applications are running? What does event viewer show?

try using e.g. "autoruns" from microsoft sysinternals to see what plugins are attaching to windows explorer. Might be a rogue context handler. you can also try "processexplorer" and look at the properties of the running windows explorer instance to see if you can identify what dll or system call(s) are eating cpu

File Explorer is extensible using so-called “Shell Extensions”. One of them is likely to blame. It could also be “security” software that injects itself into other processes.
